# cluttered layout on quick scroll or any update on page

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, next.js, tailwind-css

We are encountering a cluttered layout issue when quickly scrolling or updating the page (however, repetitive elements are not present in the DOM, it's solely a layout issue). We have built the same layout using two screens: one utilizing Next.js + Tailwind CSS and the other using Next.js + normal CSS. The issue only manifests in the repository where Tailwind CSS is used. Additionally, this problem is not reproducible on all devices. I am sharing a screen recording of the issue and device information.

- Issue video recording: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HhvPlCAwkIPjIyMiewO7BHyATi8RNt1s/view?usp=drive_link](https://stackoverflow.com)

page link

- with tailwind: [https://double-rendering-minimal.vercel.app/pcr](https://stackoverflow.com)
- without tailwind: [https://double-rendering-minimal.vercel.app/pcr-no-tailwind](https://stackoverflow.com)

github link: https://github.com/Smiles-ai/rendering-issue-demo

Note: The cluttered layout issue is not limited to the SVG teeth chart; it is randomly occurring on all elements. Additionally, this problem is not confined to this specific page; it is happening on all other pages as well. We are just sharing a sample page link for demonstration purposes.

- tailwind version -  3.4.1

Device details:

- Device: OnePlus Nord CE2 (IV2201)
- Android Version: 13 (Oxygen OS 13)
- Screen Size: 6.43 inches
- Browser: Chrome 122.0.6261.90

We have attempted to connect the Chrome debugger tool to inspect the mobile code. However, in the DOM, the cluttered layout changes are not reflected. Furthermore, since this issue is limited to very few devices, it is proving to be quite challenging to debug. Additionally, we have tried removing the teeth chart and other elements that frequently exhibit the cluttered layout, but the issue persists in other elements.[layout screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEsH2.png)

Comment: Hi Raghav, have you found any workarounds to this ? I have glitches happening on my web page in Nord 2 and I think I am having similar issue as you. I have multiple svg animation in my page.

Comment: @rupamita sarkar
plz check this
[link](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/13083)
it resolved svg related issue, but still not resolved on all pages where other component creating issue